# Using prefix tree as an input in a neural network

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

So I am working on a project and I need to analyse a prefix tree. I was wondering if I can train an MLAI to do so for me, but now I'm stuck on figuring out how to pass a tree as input. The tree can have an arbitrary number of nodes, and the data in each node maybe be a string or some other type. It is also possible that I would need to pass more than just 1 tree as input. I wanna know if what I'm aiming for is even possible or not.

Answer (score 0):

There are varied neural networks that can accept size-varied structured data as inputs, however this is not as simple as taking off the shelf MLP. At the time of writing this answer the most standard set of architectures would be **Graph Neural Networks** (since trees are just specific graphs).

Comment: Oh thank u very much for this info, I thought that neural networks can only take a fixed a set amount of inputs, ill look into this, thanks a lot